# Login with ASP Identity fails every time with "Not Allowed" (even when 'email' and 'username' have the same value))

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Registering a user works fine, as it logs in via this line:

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: model.RememberMe);
```

But if I want to log in with the same user again does not work (the Task Result always returned "Not Allowed").

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

I do realise that PasswordSignInAsync expects a USERNAME, not an EMAIL - but they are one and the same for my application.

I have tried every variation of the log in methods, including checking if the user and passwords are correct (which all succeed), passing in the user object, altering the ViewModel property name, etc.

Any ideas what needs to change?

Similar issue for context: [ASP.NET Identity Provider SignInManager Keeps Returning Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430094/asp-net-identity-provider-signinmanager-keeps-returning-failure)

Thank you.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I looked at the source code here - https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs.

NotAllowed is only set here:

```cs
protected virtual async Task<SignInResult> PreSignInCheck(TUser user)
{
    if (!await CanSignInAsync(user))
    {
        return SignInResult.NotAllowed;
    }
    if (await IsLockedOut(user))
    {
        return await LockedOut(user);
    }
    return null;
}
```

So I drilled down into CanSignInAsync...

```
public virtual async Task<bool> CanSignInAsync(TUser user)
{
    if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail && !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
    {
        Logger.LogWarning(0, "User {userId} cannot sign in without a confirmed email.", await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
        return false;
    }
    if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber && !(await UserManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user)))
    {
        Logger.LogWarning(1, "User {userId} cannot sign in without a confirmed phone number.", await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
        return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Oh, I know where this is going. Let's take a look at my Startup.cs Configuration.

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    ...
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    ...
}
```

Oh dear, OK.

All I had to do was pop into the database and set my user as EmailConfirmed = true. [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK).

"Not Allowed" makes sense, but there was no error message that came back with it - so it wasn't the best way to know what's going on. Luckily .NET Core is easy to dive into the source code with.

Comment: Nice find! In my case I was seeding the db and didn't set EmailConfirmed=True during seeding. Updated my seeding code, deleted the seeded record, restarted the app. I can login with my seeded admin account and life is good...

Comment: I just fell into this hole - fortunately - you save me, thanks!

Comment: My friend. I was about to run into a wall after battling with this for hours. You saved me. Thanks a million.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, this helped me also! I was implementing a change username and I think when I changed their email it auto-set their confirmed back to false. Either way when a user changed their username they were no longer able to log in even though they were getting their new username and current password correct.

Answer (score 13):

If you haven't added email confirmation, check your Startup.cs Configuration.

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    //...
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    //...
}
```

It should be `false` This causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to make sure you are adding the correct display attribute to the email property of your LoginViewModel so it does't blow up when it notices input that is not an email address:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username/Email")]
    public string Email { get; set;
```

Next, instead of model.Email in the PasswordSignInAsync method, use user.UserName, like this:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Re: Display attribute - isn't that simply what the label displays on the front end? Does it affect the model itself in any other way?

Re: Instead of model.Email... - I have tried your suggestion as well, including looking up the user object and passing through the user.UserName value. It's just a string value, so I can't see why it would return "Not Allowed" every time, no matter what - especially since UserName and Email are the exact same.

Cheers

Comment: Have a look at this link and let me know if it helps, pal. http://techbrij.com/asp-net-core-identity-login-email-username

Comment: Hey mate, I appreciate the help - but I actually want to keep using the username as the email. The issue seems to be that I'm unable to sign in with an email using PasswordSignInAsync (even if the username is an email address email).

The only thing I can think of is that PasswordSignInAsync doesn't actually allow an email address format - even though you can register with one. 

I might decompile and see how it's working under the hood.

Comment: Hey mate, I have found the issue - it's to do with my configuration. I'll post my answer belong. Just wanted to say thanks for the help anyway :).

Answer (score 0):

In `Program.cs`, replace the below code:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

with:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

It will work.